# IE9: Prevent Accidental Modification of Production Data when testing in the Development Enviroment

Tags: script, internet-explorer-9

Is there an IE9 script or plugin I can use that would alert me whenever I land on a certain domain?

We have a production and dev environment for the intranet where I work and it is easy to get the 2 environments mixed up and corrupt production data.

I don't want to modify each app in the system to alert me when I'm in dev or production. I'd rather have a browser script run on each page load, check the domain, and alert me ifI am in production.

I know this would be easy in Chrome or Firefox but I must use IE9 for my testing.